# New parse framework doesn't have PFFacebookUtils?

Tags: swift, xcode, parse-platform, pffacebookutils

Guys I am in desperate need of help!

All I want to do is have a login with Facebook and have that data uploaded to Parse. But the issue I am having is, when I use the old Parse framework, PFFacebookUtils works, but doesn't upload anything to Heroku via Parse. And when I use the new Parse framework, it allows me to upload data to Heroku, but it doesn't let me use PFFacebookUtils. Can anyone please shed some light on this?!

Here is the code that works with the old framework and lets me use PFFacebookUtils, but doesn't upload anything to Heroku.

```
    Parse.setApplicationId("My App ID",

                           clientKey: "My Client Key")
```

Here is the code that works with the new Parse framework and lets me upload to Heroku, but with this new framework PFFacebookUtils no longer works.

let parseConfiguration = ParseClientConfiguration(block: { (ParseMutableClientConfiguration) -> Void in

```
        ParseMutableClientConfiguration.applicationId = "My App ID"

        ParseMutableClientConfiguration.clientKey = "My Client Key"

        ParseMutableClientConfiguration.server = "My Client URL"

    })        

    Parse.initializeWithConfiguration(parseConfiguration)
```

I could honestly use any help provided, I've been running around in circles trying to find a solution. It seems like if I want to use Facebook login via PFFacebookUtils I have to use the old Parse framework but that doesn't upload to Heroku anymore.

If there is a different way to use Facebook login without PFFacebookUtils then I'd be happy to use that because then I can use this new Parse framework that actually uploads to Heroku.

Many thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you're doing your package management, but you need to include other Frameworks as well. For instance, if using cocoapods, these are the frameworks you would want to include

```
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit’
pod ‘FBSDKLoginKit’
pod ‘FBSDKShareKit’
pod 'ParseFacebookUtilsV4’
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I deleted all the old frameworks and found a ParseFacebookUtils framework that works. After adding the new framework, I just had to:

## import ParseFacebookUtils